# CSS input field styling magic

Tags: css, forms, cross-browser

I am trying to style an input field and some buttons in a consistent way, but there seems to be some magic going on. Event though the input has the exact same classes as the buttons it is slightly higher. Also the placeholder text is vertically aligned differently the the inputted text (one pixel higher). Can this be solved with a cross-browser solution?

Edit: As pointed out by Jan Turoň the line height fixed the problem in Webkit. Now, if you check the codepen in Firefox you'll notice that the  element still has a 1px border. How to get rid of that?

Thx, PS

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbtJI)

HTML

```
<form action="">
  <a href=""class="btn">Button</a>
  <input type="text" class="btn" placeholder="input"/>
  <button class="btn">Login</button>
  <a href=""class="btn">Button</a>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.btn, input, button {

  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;

  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;

  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  padding: 7px 12px 8px 12px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;

}
```

Comment: Changing this line-height to 17px solved ur vertical spacing issue with the input being larger...  Probably another way to do it also http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vbtJI

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using top and bottom padding on form elements.  Instead, use absolute heights with correct line heights to get the desired effect.  This way, no matter what browser you look through, it will always be the same height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `line-height` doesn't shrink the input height below `font-size` plus some pixels [see the MDN info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height):

> On replaced inline elements, like buttons or other input element, line-height has no effect.

Just remove the `line-height` and you should get what you want even without applying `height`style. Setting `line-height` to 130% also does seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to solve this for days and every solution is not whole, and not working in different browsers.

I find that this code do the work:

```
float: left;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
height: 33px;
```

I have updated Codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvqRwE